# How to immediately get id token from google play services Unity Plugin

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I'm using https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity plugin to sign in user with his google account , and then i want to get Id Token and send it to my server and register an account for this user in my own database.this is my code to get Id token :

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate(success =>
{
    if (success)
    {
        Debug.Log("Id Token :");
        Debug.LogFormat("{0}", PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetIdToken());
        Debug.Log("End Of Id Token");
    }
});
```

The problem is the first time it prints just empty string , when i call this for the second time (or a moment later) it prints the token. I want to get token **immediately**  or with a **callback** to make sure that token is recieved .

How to make sure that token is recieved? is there any callback for this?

Thanks

Comment: I've noticed the same thing happen with me, using a native plugin that I copied/modified for my Unity project. I would always get a null the very first time and could find no way to work around it. I think it's because it takes a while to receive the token from Google, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They changed the plugin in new version and now

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetIdToken(Callback)
```

has a callback function.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to identify a user on your own web service it would be better to use the server auth code. Send this to your server and get the user identity via jwt from google.

```
                GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject.RunOnGameThread(() => {

                    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetServerAuthCode((CommonStatusCodes status, string code) =>
                    {                            
                        Debug.Log("Status: " + status.ToString());
                        Debug.Log("Code: " + code);

                    });

                });
```