# Play Games Plugin For Unity - Get Access Token - Null

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I am trying to use the Google Play Games Plugin to get an access token from the user to use to authenticate a player in GameSparks. The problem is when I try to get the access token using

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetAccessCode();
```

it returns null, and I get this error:

```
!!! [Play Games Plugin DLL] 08/12/16 17:32:30 -04:00 WARNING: Non-success returned from fetch: 8
```

I am testing this on android.

I have linked an android app to play game services, and I have linked a web app to use the client id and client secret to put in GameSparks Google+ Integration. I have also put the client id from the web app into the Android Setup on Unity in the web client id section.

Is there something I setup wrong, or does the GetAccessCode() function just now work

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Based from this [thread](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1067), the correct way to get an ID token is to use [`GetServerAuthCode`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount) and send the auth code to your server. There, exchange the code for a token to use for the API calls.

Comment: Look at this answer it may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030826/how-to-immediately-get-id-token-from-google-play-services-unity-plugin

Comment: Yeah, I saw that question too, but the thing that was troubling me, was that it was getting an ID Token. Gamesparks requests an access token to authenticate the user. I'm not sure whether or not there's a difference between ID Tokens and Access Tokens.